# Auto-Clicker, with start / stop hot keys

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I'm trying to recreate an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) script that I use on my Windows machine.

Here's a parsed down version of my AutoHotkey script and what it's meant to do:

1. Set X to 1
2. If shift+G is pressed, set X to 0 (ON SWITCH)
3. If shift+S is pressed, set X to 1 (OFF SWITCH)
4. While X=0
   4a.   Loop
   4b.   Click left mouse button
   4c.   time=random time between 0.2-0.5 seconds
   5c.   Delay "time" length

I've installed [`cliclick`](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/) and am trying to work through that, but could use some help with the AppleScript syntax and maybe there is a better way to get at this?

Here is what I have so far.

```
set switch to 0

if shft + G then -- unsure how to set hot keys, maybe keyboard hot key input?
    set switch to 1
end if

if shift + f then -- unsure how to set hot keys, maybe keyboard hot key input?
    set switch to 0
end if

while switch = 1
    
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  c:."
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke 5 using {command down}
        delay 0.2 -- still need to randomize
    end tell
    
end while
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with your **AppleScript** and instead of pointing out everything that not right with it, let me just say that you can not replicate, with basic vanilla **AppleScript**, what **AutoHotkey** did for you in this use case. In **Windows**, the  **AutoHotkey** program is memory resident and is listening to the _message stream_ so it knows what to do when a given _keyboard shortcut_ is pressed. Basic vanilla **AppleScript** does not provide a mechanism to listen to the _message stream_ as in **Windows** and then react to a  given _keyboard shortcut_ when pressed.

Comment: That said, in your **AppleScript** _code_, the `if` _statements_ are malformed because  there is no  mechanism to listen for a given _keyboard shortcut_ was pressed. The `while` _statement_ is malformed, for **AppleScript** you have to use `repeat while switch = 1` and `end repeat`. **System Events** is going to send the `keystroke` to whichever _application_ is _frontmost_ and having not specified which _application_ it should go to, it may create unwanted results of just fail altogether.